# OAuthTAI Authentication failed with Status = 401, WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="imfAuthentication", scope="UserAuthRealm" in MFP Version 7.1

Tags: oauth-2.0, realm, ibm-mobilefirst

***Problem:***

I am using MFP 7.1 and oauth.tai_1.0.0.jar in my android application for app authenticity and have defined the realm on MFP's end. Each time I try to register to the application I see  in the log

> OAuthTAI Authentication failed with Status = 401, WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="imfAuthentication", scope="UserAuthRealm"

This is not preventing the application flow. I am only getting this error in the log and this error is seen before the realm class's init method is initialized and after that everything works fine.

I am wondering why I am getting this error.

***Analysis:***

I have checked the challenge handler in android, it is fine. I also did a fresh installation of the app in order to be sure of a new access token being sent from MFP.
I had also checked in MFP' Oauth jar and checked the 401 error case, it checks for invalid_token and invalid_authorization. But in my case, none of these two are there as I am not getting this in error description. I have the custom authenticator class defined which is mapped to UserAuthReal, code below:

**CustomUserAuthenticator.java**

```
package com.ibm.mfp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext;
import com.worklight.server.auth.api.AuthenticationResult;
import com.worklight.server.auth.api.AuthenticationStatus;
import com.worklight.server.auth.api.MissingConfigurationOptionException;
import com.worklight.server.auth.api.UserIdentity;
import com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticator;

public class CustomUserAuthenticator implements WorkLightAuthenticator {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -548850541866024092L;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomUserAuthenticator.class.getName());

private String pin;
private String userName;
private String uniqueID;
private String userNumber;
private String userAuthFlag;
private String registrationNumber;
protected Map<String, Object> authenticationData;

public void init(Map<String, String> options) throws MissingConfigurationOptionException {
    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator initialized");
}

public AuthenticationResult processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        boolean isAccessToProtectedResource) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String clientID = AuthenticationContext.getCurrentClientId();
    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator :: processRequest : clientID : " + clientID);

    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator :: processRequest : request.getRequestURI() :" + requestURI);
    String requestQueryString = request.getQueryString();
    requestQueryString = null;
    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator :: processRequest : request.getQueryString() :" + requestQueryString);

    // Request the epin from the user
    if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/ADIBMBA/auth/v2/auth")) {
        this.pin = request.getParameter("pin");
        this.userName= request.getParameter("userName");
        this.uniqueID = request.getParameter("uniqueID");
        this.userNumber = request.getParameter("userNumber");
        this.userAuthFlag = request.getParameter("userAuthFlag");
        this.registrationNumber = request.getParameter("registrationNumber");

        if (null != this.customerNumber) {
            logger.info(
                    "CustomUserAuthenticator :: processRequest : request.getRequestURI() : getParameter customerNumber : "
                            + this.customerNumber);
        } 

        if (null != pin && pin.length() > 0) {

            return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
            response.getWriter().print("{\"authStatus\":\"required\", \"errorMessage\":\"Please enter epin\"}");
            return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED);
        }
    }

    if (!isAccessToProtectedResource) {

        return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.REQUEST_NOT_RECOGNIZED);
    }

    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.getWriter().print("{\"authStatus\":\"required\"}");
    return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED);
}

public boolean changeResponseOnSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

    String requestURI2 = request.getRequestURI();
    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator :: changeResponseOnSuccess : request ");
    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator :: changeResponseOnSuccess : response ");

    // first worked partially with if
    // (request.getRequestURI().contains("/ADIBMBA/auth/v2/auth")){
    if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/ADIBMBA/mainapps/services/apis/App/iOSnative")
            || (request.getRequestURI().contains("/ADIBMBA/auth/v2/auth"))) {
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        response.getWriter().print("{\"authStatus\":\"complete\"}");

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public AuthenticationResult processAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        String errorMessage) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator :: processAuthenticationFailure");

    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.getWriter().print("{\"authStatus\":\"failed\", \"errorMessage\":" + errorMessage + ","
            + (String) authenticationData.get("error") + "}");

    return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED);
}

public AuthenticationResult processRequestAlreadyAuthenticated(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    logger.info("CustomUserAuthenticator :: processRequestAlreadyAuthenticated");
return

AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.
REQUEST_NOT_RECOGNIZED);
}

public Map<String, Object> getAuthenticationData() {
    authenticationData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    authenticationData.put("userName", userName);
    authenticationData.put("uniqueID", uniqueID);
    authenticationData.put("pin", pin);
    authenticationData.put("userNumber", userNumber);
    authenticationData.put("userAuthFlag", userAuthFlag);
    authenticationData.put("registrationNumber", registrationNumber);
    return authenticationData;
}

public HttpServletRequest getRequestToProceed(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        UserIdentity userIdentity) throws IOException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public WorkLightAuthenticator clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    CustomUserAuthenticator otherAuthenticator = (CustomUserAuthenticator) super.clone();
    return otherAuthenticator;
}
}
```

***Summary:***

If the application flow is normal then why i am getting this OAuthTAI 401 error in log. Suppose If it is a problem related to token & id token then i should not be able to access protected resource data. Application should not allow me to proceed further.

Comment: MFP does not use OAuthTAI to work. You are using this in your code. That 401 is coming from OAuthTAI , yes? 
What exactly are you trying to achieve? Use OAuthTAI for OAuth? Or do you intend for MFP server to give you that?

Comment: @VivinK I have used OAuthTAI to protect java resources since i have java adapters. I have followed the OAuthTAI from the following link [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/r_oauth_filter_was_wasl.html) . My purpose of using OAuth is to just authorize the users.

Comment: Why not use MFP's OAuth security to protect your Java adapters ? I have not understood why the OAuthTAI approach when MFP can do it for you.
The article you pointed out is to protect external resources ( not deployed on MFP). Are you trying to protect a MFP Java adapter or external?

Comment: I have java adapter exposed as rest services and protected with @OauthSecurity="realm", means only valid user can access the resources. The resources are accessed using adapters only and those adapters are deployed on MFP console. E.g. a server has MFP installed and on it's console, i have adapters deployed now my application access the protected adapters using OAuth user authentication with MFP's Trust Association Interceptor (TAI) . This is where i am getting this TAI error in log.

Answer (score 0):

From the description and comments, it appears you have mixed up Liberty's OAuth TAI and MFP's OAuth security model.

MFP's OAuth security model is used to protect MFP resources ( adapters and runtime endpoints), while Liberty's OAuth TAI is to protect resources deployed on Liberty server ( eg: web applications).

The link you followed details steps using which MFP server can act as the OAuth server for resources deployed in Liberty server.

From the description and the custom Authenticator that extends `WorklightAuthenticator` you are depending on the security validation to be done by MFP's security framework. If the requirement is for your MFP adapters to be protected by OAuth security and the device begins by obtaining an OAuth token from MFP server, then you should use MFP's OAuth security and not resort to Liberty OAuth TAI. MFP's OAuth security framework works out of the box, without any need to configure TAI.

Refer to the following links for a better understanding and working samples:

a) [MFP OAuth security model](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/authentication-concepts/oauth-based-security-model/)

b) [Java adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/java-adapter/)

c) [Custom Authenticator](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/CustomAuth)